# How to add click handler for prev/next buttons from Vuetify date-picker

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

[image]

How can I add `click`-event listeners to the previous-month and next-month buttons from the Vuetify date-picker (circled in screenshot above)?

```html
<template>
  <v-row justify="center">
    <v-date-picker @click:month="dateChange"></v-date-picker>
  </v-row>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    dateChange(date) {
      console.log(date)
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [template ref](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#template-refs) on the `<v-date-picker>` to query its DOM for its inner buttons, and add event listeners on them. The previous and next buttons have the `.v-btn` class, and an `aria-label` of "Previous month" and "Next month", respectively:

```html
<template>
  <v-date-picker ref="datepicker" />
<template>

<script>
export default {
  async mounted() {
    await this.$nextTick()
    const prevBtn = this.$refs.datepicker.$el.querySelector('.v-btn[aria-label="Previous month"]')
    prevBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log('previous button clicked')
    })

    const nextBtn = this.$refs.datepicker.$el.querySelector('.v-btn[aria-label="Next month"]')
    nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log('next button clicked')
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/yLKKojd?editors=1010)